# Flash Crossdomain

Tags: cross-domain, flash, vk

Similiar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311597/get-vk-video-direct-links-on-client-side-ip-html5

VK.com is a Russian social network sites which also allows you to host videos. They allow you to embed their videos but because of their cross-domain policy, you can't use ajax/flash requests to get the video page on the client side. However, this swf file does that without loading a cross-domain file? (I sniffed the network traffic, it seems as if the flash file doesn't request a crossdomain.xml file but rather directly load the vk.com page http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=196471971&id=167752304&hash=9fd63185df970616)

The URL for the swf file is
http://www.jethdfilmizle.com/veka.swf?file=vk.com%2Fvideo_ext.php%3Foid%3D189406059%26id%3D163663575%26hash%3D388c8150742ccb2f&otobaslat=0

Can anybody explain how this works?

Comment: has you found answer to your question?

Comment: @V_B unfortunately, still haven't found the answer.